# android-mapviewballoons, onBalloonTap does not work if I build with ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard

I'm developing a project using android-mapviewballoons (https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons). I extended com.readystatesoftware.mapviewballoons.BalloonItemizedOverlay with a customized class called CustomItemizedOverlay and in this class I redefined onBalloonTap(int index).

When I build a signed APK without using proguard everything works fine: the application runs, I can tap on the map, see the Balloon, tap on the balloon and, via onBalloonTap, get further information about the point I've been tapping on.
When I build with proguard active the application runs flawlessly except for the balloon: I can tap on the map, see the balloon but when I click on it nothing happens. It's just as the balloon itself was transparent, if there's something behind it it gets selected, just as the balloon was not there.

I tried removing features from proguard.cfg one by one, but couldn't find what's happening. I tried with -dontoptimize but didn't work. I think that maybe the issue comes from the obfuscation process, but I can't avoid obfuscation because if I put the -dontobfuscate directive building fails with a "Dalvik Error 1" message.

In the "library" section of my proguard file I have:
(...)

```
-libraryjars /home/marco/workspace/../Scrivania/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google_inc_-7/libs/maps.jar

-libraryjars /home/marco/workspace/android-mapviewballoons/bin/android-mapviewballoons.jar
```

In the "keep" section I have (among others):

```
-keep public class * extends com.google.android.maps.MapActivity

-keep class com.posteitaliane.postemobile.CoverFlow

-keepclassmembers public class com.readystatesoftware.mapviewballoons.BalloonItemizedOverlay.** {
                public static * ;
        }

-keepclassmembers public class com.posteitaliane.postemobile.CustomItemizedOverlay.** {
                public static * ;
        }

-keepclassmembers public class com.readystatesoftware.mapviewballoons.** {
                public static * ;
        }
```

Could somebody please help me? I just don't know how to create a signed build without breaking proguard or losing this mapBalloon feature.

Thank you in advance

Edit 2012/03/19
I solved the issue by importing a later version of mapviewballoons in the project and fixing the code to fit the new features of mapviewballoons itself. See https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons/issues/16